# In solidjs, how to avoid multi execution of the computed when the dependencies have some kind of relationship?

Tags: solid-js

If a computed value depends on 2 signals (S1 and S2), and S2 is both a signal (can be changed individually) and a computed value of S1 (through an effect), then when you change S1, the computed value will always run twice, first when S1 changed, second when S2 changed because of S1.

```
function Counter() {
  const [a, setA] = createSignal(1);
  const [b, setB] = createSignal(2);
  const sum = () => {
    console.log('sum')
    return a() + b();
  }

  createEffect(() => setB(a()))

  return (
    <div>
    <div>{sum()}</div>
    <button onClick={() => setA(a() + 1)}>Inc a - {a()}</button>
    <button onClick={() => setB(b() + 1)}>Inc b - {b()}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the double execution since we know for sure the first one is not needed? createMemo doesn't work here because both S1 and S2 changed

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/96549ff3-4c4e-4448-a98b-5e2ed1fabea7

**EDIT:**
Based on snnsnn's answer, this can be achieved by using "on" with createMemo

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/30d1e873-d566-4e41-adca-c2bf5e9c5d43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `batch`function to update multiple signals at once, the effects will be executed once. That is the whole purpose of `batch`function.

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#batch

If you need to observe one of the signals but needed the second one for its value, use `on` function for explicitly tracking the one you need to observe. You can use an array to track more than one signal explicitly:

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#on

PS: Never update a state inside an effect that reads the state, you will have an infinite loop. If you really need to, use a callback:

```js
setState(prev => prev + 1);
```

Comment: batch doesn't apply here, since I'm only changing a. But on with createMemo solves the problem